# working with non default dataSource in groovy controller/service

Tags: grails, groovy, datasource

I have 2 datasources defined in my dataSource.groovy one is default

```
dataSource {
 all variables
}
```

other one is readonly

```
dataSource_readonly {
 all variables
}
```

Initially I used to use default datasource in my controller so:

```
class myController {
javax.sql.DataSource dataSource
def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
.............
```

so now to use the other datasource do I need to do something like this ?

```
class myController {
javax.sql.DataSource dataSource_readonly
def sql = new Sql(dataSource_readonly)
.............
```

Comment: 2 quick questions; 1) why are you trying to get a direct connection to the DataSource rather than going through GORM?  2) Are you using Grails 2.0RC1?

Comment: Hi, this is the way I am executing sql queries in my controllers, I do sql.rows(myquery). Also we are using grails 1.3.7, so not v2, I am thinking of upgrading it to ver 2 and try the datasource addition instead of using the datasource plugin.

Comment: I am not able to install grails 2.0RC1, its giving me invalid maximum heap size error on startup, I am going to use 1.3.7 with datasource plugin for multiple datasource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like that:

```
groovy.sql.Sql connection = Sql.newInstance(ConfigurationHolder.config.dataSource.url,
                ConfigurationHolder.config.dataSource.username,
                ConfigurationHolder.config.dataSource.password,
                ConfigurationHolder.config.dataSource.driverClassName)
        connection.execute("UPDATE ......")
```

Comment: I am trying to have 2 datasources so that one is readonly, other is readwrite (for same database username), I achieved this using the datasources plugin.

Comment: So If I do this in every closure in my controller (even using my previous method), am I creating new connections in every closure? I should be resusing this connection object everywhere possible isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just like you can with the default datasource, you can declare a property in your controller/service with the custom datasource name, and grails will automatically initialize your controller/service with the custom datasource bean:

```
class MyController {
    def dataSource_readonly

    def myAction = {
        def sql = new groovy.sql.Sql(dataSource_readonly)
    }
}
```